# How to remove only News from Siri Suggestions

Tags: spotlight, ios

How do I remove *only News* from Siri Suggestions?

I like the quick access to frequently used apps and contacts there.

I don't like being informed of the latest murder spree, political news, or military calamity every time I'm just trying to get to the Mail app or find my wife's contact.

Is there a way to fix this terrible feature?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but as of today's current release (iOS 9.2) that's not possible. It could change in future updates, though. You can suggest that feature to Apple.

Comment: Bummer. Is there at least a way to configure what news items it shows? It seems to ignore all my favorites and show me constant terrorism and politics